# Java swt handleevent event sometimes null

Tags: java, eclipse, events, swt, listener

I am writing a listener to shell events in Java. I have a codesnippet which looks like this:

```
Listener shellListener = new Listener() {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        if (event == null || event.widget == null) {
            return;
        }
        // do some other stuff
    }
}
```

Sometimes I got a null event or the widget of the event object is null. For now, I catch them manually. But my question is:

How can a null event or the widget of an event be null? I am using Eclipse and reproducing it (to further investigate the reason) is not so easy as I thought.

Comment: Could you post a minimal code example that shows your problem? Do you create events yourself somewhere in your code?

Comment: No. It is an Eclipse plugin and in this plugin I am tracking all opened or closed dialogs in Eclipse. In the handleEvent method, I am tracking events, like SWT.Activate, SWT.Close and so on.

Comment: Could you create a minimal example (no Eclipse-RCP, plain SWT) that shows your problem?